# shorten multiple if statements for the same variable

Tags: javascript, shortcut

So I need to check the value of one variable and set the value of another appropriately. What I'm currently doing which I suspect there's a shortcut for is:

```
if(i==a){j=foo}
if(i==b){j=bar}
if(i==c){j=etc}
...
```

I'm hoping there's some sort of code that looks something like:

```
if(i==
a: j=foo,
b: j=bar,
c: j=etc,
....
)
```

obviously that syntax is made up and not right. But I'm just hoping there's some way of saving me typing out an if statement for every possible thing. All the other articles I can find are trying to set multiple values of i to the same value of j which is not helping here.

Thanks for help!

Comment: why don't you use a `switch` ?

Comment: Oh perfect. I didn't know about that function! Thanks for pointing it out to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to try the `switch(variable) {...}` statement like this:

```
switch(i){
    case a : j = foo; break;
    case b : j = bar; break;
    case c : j = etc; break;
    default : // i was not equal to any of those
}
```